# How to improve the performance while using ExecutorService with thread timeout capabilities?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, executorservice, resttemplate

I am not a Multithreading Expert but I am seeing some performance issues with my current code which is using `ExecutorService`.

I am working on a project in which I need to make a HTTP URL call to my server and if it is taking too long time to respond then timeout the call. Currently it is returning simple JSON String back..

Current requirement I have is for `10 ms`. Within `10 ms` it should be able to get the data back from the server. I guess its possible since it is just an HTTP call to server within the same datacenter.

My client program and actual servers are within same datacenter and ping time latency is `0.5 ms` between them so it should be doable for sure..

I am using `RestTemplate` for this to make the URL call.

Below is my code which I have wrote for me which uses `ExecutorService` and `Callables` -

```
public class URLTest {

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public String getData() {
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Task());
        String response = null;

        try {
            System.out.println("Started..");
            response = future.get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            System.out.println("Finished!");
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("Terminated!");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Below is my Task class which implements `Callable` interface -

```
class Task implements Callable<String> {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public String call() throws Exception {
        //  TimerTest timer = TimerTest.getInstance();  // line 3
            String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
        //  timer.getDuration();    // line 4

        return response;

    }
}
```

And below is my code in another class `DemoTest` which calls the `getData` method in `URLTest` class `500 times` and measure the 95th percentile of it end to end -

```
public class DemoTest { 
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        URLTest bc = new URLTest();

        // little bit warmup
        for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
            bc.getData();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= 500; i++) {
            TimerTest timer = TimerTest.getInstance(); // line 1
            bc.getData();
            timer.getDuration(); // line 2
        }

        // this method prints out the 95th percentile
        logPercentileInfo();

    }
}
```

With the above code as it is, I am always seeing 95th percentile as `14-15 ms` (which is bad for my use case as it is end to end flow and that's what I need to measure).

I am surprised why? Is `ExectuorFramework` adding all the latency here?. May be Each task is submitted, and the submitting thread is waiting (via future.get) until the task is finished..

My main goal is to reduce the latency here as much as possible.. My use case is simple, Make a URL call to one of my server with a TIMEOUT feature enabled, meaning if the server is taking lot of time to response, then Timeout the whole call. Customer will call our code from there application which can be multithreaded as well..

Is there anything I am missing or some other flavors of `ExecutorService` I need to use? How can I improve my performance here? Any suggestions will be of great help..

Any example will be greatly appreciated.. I was reading about `ExecutorCompletionService` not sure whether I should use this or something else..

Comment: Really don't understand what you expect to accomplish re: web server performance by fiddling with the thread pool implementation?  Look at the web server and web client...!  You need to set a timeout on the web client so that it actually gives up.  With a timeout on the future you're just abandoning the task, but the worker thread still sits there trying to do it until it's done.

Comment: This is looking pretty single threaded to me...

Comment: It is not the executor framework at fault here.  Something is taking longer than you expected.  I'd recommend looking into running a Java profiler.  You might also log the wall-clock millis of the various parts of your system to see what's taking so long.

Comment: Also, even though you are timing out your job, it will continue to execute and take system resources in the background.  Killing the RPC is important.

Comment: @pamphlet: I need to have synchronous and asynchronous method for my use case, one to block the call.. And other to send back the future.. Depending on these methods, client can call any method as they like.. So that's why I have this..

Comment: @Gray: I am using system.nanotime here to measure the performance.. One thing I found very strange here is, if I comment out line 1 and line 2 in DemoTest class and uncomment line 3 and line 4 in Task class and then run the program again it will start giving me 95th percentile as 3 ms. So not sure why end to end flow gives me 95th percentile as `14-15 ms`?

Comment: Why not mock that calls, and see what else could be the cause of this ?

Comment: @Affe: I have a REST service deployed on one of my servers so I am hitting that rest service using REST Template..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for your observation that you are measuring 15 ms on the outside, but only 3 ms on the inside, my bet is that the construction of the `RestTemplate` takes the difference. This could be fixed by refactoring.

Note that `RestTemplate` is a heavyweight, thread-safe object, and is designed to be deployed as an *application-wide singleton*. Your current code is in critical violation of this intent.

---

If you need asynchronous HTTP requests, you should really use an asynchronous HTTP library such an `AsyncHttpClient`, based on Netty underneath, which is again based on Java NIO. That means that you don't need to occupy a thread per an outstanding HTTP request. `AsyncHttpClient` also works with Futures so you'll have an API you are used to. It can also work with callbacks, which is preferred for the asynchronous approach.

However, even if you keep your current synchronous library, you should at the very least configure a timeout on the REST client instead of letting it run its course.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.. Any thoughts what changes I should make? And it will be a great if you can provide an example with AsyncHttpClient.. I am just trying to understand how it will fit in my current use case..

Comment: To validate this hypothesis, just make the `RestTemplate` static.

Comment: AsyncHttpClient doesn't on its own have RESTful convenience, but there are probably libraries which handle that. On the other hand, I would first have a look into the capabilities of `RestTemplate` itself in this regard.

Comment: Does it matter either way, static or instance.?

RestTemplate's methods for making HTTP requests are thread safe so whether you have a RestTemplate instance per Task instance or a shared instance for all Task instances is irrelevant (except for garbage collection) I guess.. correct me if I am wrong..

Comment: `RestTemplate` is a heavyweight object, maintaning the complete IO infrastructure, connection pools, etc. It should definitely make a huge difference. That is, unless I am completely wrong about the design of `RestTemplate`, which is also possible.

Comment: I tried the above mentioned approach. Brough down the cycle time from 15ms to around 10 ms for my application.

Answer (score 3):

> then run the program again it will start giving me 95th percentile as 3 ms. So not sure why end to end flow gives me 95th percentile as 14-15 ms

You are generating the tasks faster than you can process them.  This means the longer you run the tests, the further behind it gets as it is queuing them up.  I would expect if you made this 2000 requests you would see latencies up to 4x what you do now.  The bottlneck could be on the client side (in which case more threads would help) but quite likely the bottleneck is on the server side in which case more threads could make it worse.

---

The default behaviour for HTTP is to establish a new TCP connection for each request.  The connection time for a new TCP connection can be up to 20 ms easily even if you have two machines side by side.  I suggest looking at using HTTp/1.1 and maintain a [persistent connection.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)

BTW You can ping from one side of London to the other in 0.5 ms. However, getting below 1 ms with HTTP reliably is tricky as the protocol is not designed for low latency.  It is designed for use on high latency networks.

Note: you cannot see latencies below 25 ms and 100 ms is plenty fast enough for most web requests. It is with these sort of assumption that HTTP was designed.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the suggestion.. There is one very strange thing I would like to tell you.. May be that can give you some clue - One thing I found very strange here is, if I comment out line 1 and line 2 in DemoTest class and uncomment line 3 and line 4 in Task class and then run the program again it will start giving me 95th percentile as 3 ms. So not sure why end to end flow gives me 95th percentile as 14-15 ms?

Comment: To interpret, OP has 3 ms for the REST call itself, but 15 ms for the future call.

Comment: You also have an increased delay from starting the threads.  Your code won't be compiled until it is executed 10,000 times and I normally ignore the first 10K or first 2 seconds of a benchmark.

Comment: @PeterLawrey To answer on that question. I have already ran it couple of time before measure it.. Currently I am running 500 times for warming up then I start measuring the call as shown in my `DemoTest class`. I can increase the warmup number to see whether it affects any performance or not..

Comment: @Webby It occurs to me you are generating requests faster than you are processing them so they are queuing.  A longer run should appear to be slower as the queue will get longer. See my answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I see, so in short you are saying, I should sleep for couple of milliseconds before making any call to my `getData` method?

Comment: @Webby if you slow down the producer, e.g. add Thread.sleep(1) after each call, you should see better numbers.  You wouldn't do this in reality which is one of the hazzards of trying to benchmark this system.  I suggest turning the problem around and say measure fast can you send requests and ensure 99% are less than 10 ms.

Comment: @Webby and I would run the test for at least 10 seconds, ideally an hour or over night.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45662/discussion-between-webby-and-peter-lawrey)