# How to use RestTemplate efficiently in Multithreaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, connection-pooling, resttemplate

I am working on a project in which I need to make a HTTP URL call to my server which is running `Restful Service` which returns back the response as a JSON String.

Below is my main code which is using the `future` and `callables` -

```
public class TimeoutThreadExample {

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public String getData() {
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Task());
        String response = null;

        try {
            response = future.get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Below is my `Task` class which implements the `Callable` interface and uses the `RestTemplate`...

```
class Task implements Callable<String> {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public String call() throws Exception {

        String url = "some_url";
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

        return response;
    }
}
```

And now I have below code in another class `DemoTest` which calls the `getData` method in `TimeoutThreadExample` class `5000 times` sequentially -

```
public class DemoTest { 
   public static void main(String[] args) {

        TimeoutThreadExample bc = new TimeoutThreadExample();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5000; i++) {
        //  TimerTest timer = TimerTest.getInstance(); // line 1
            bc.getData();
        //  timer.getDuration(); // line 2
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is should `RestTemplate` be static here in my `Task class` as if I see it correctly, I am recreating the whole connection pool for each request in `RestTemplate` which is not the right way I guess..

**NOTE:** If I am making RestTemplate static, then I see better performance end to end as compared to non static `RestTemplate` after commenting out line1 and line2 in `DemoTest` class which measures the performance.

In general what is the right way to use `RestTemplate` in Multithreading environment? Currently I am calling sequentially `getData` method 5000 times one by one but some customer will call it in a multithreaded way so need to know what is the best way to have RestTemplate in a multithreaded environment..

May be to use ConnectionFactory in the RestTemplate constructor? Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:-**

```
public class TimeoutThreadExample {

    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public String getData() {
        Future<String> future = executor.submit(new Task(restTemplate));
        String response = null;

        try {
            response = future.get(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

And below my `TaskClass` -

```
class Task implements Callable<String> {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public Task(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public String call() throws Exception {

        String url = "some_url";
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to improve the performance while using ExecutorService with thread timeout capabilities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241036/how-to-improve-the-performance-while-using-executorservice-with-thread-timeout-c)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Correct me if I didn't understand your question. It seems very similar to the previous one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21145558/resttemplate-should-be-static-globally-declared).

There, we determined that `RestTemplate` is thread-safe. There is therefore no reason not to share it wherever it makes sense to, ie. wherever you are using it in the same way. 
Your example seems like the perfect place to do so.

As you stated, recreating a new instance of `RestTemplate` for each `Task` instance is wasteful.

I would create the `RestTemplate` in `TimeoutThreadExample` and pass it to the `Task` as a constructor argument.

```
class Task implements Callable<String> {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public Task(RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    public String call() throws Exception {

        String url = "some_url";
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

        return response;
    }
}
```

This way you share the `RestTemplate` instance between all your `Task` objects.

Note that `RestTemplate` uses `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` to create its connections.

Comment: I see.. So in short they both are same.. making a static in Task class? or using DI by passing around the objects?

Comment: RestTemplate is thread-safe but you also have to be sure the underling http connection manager is threadsafe, for e.g. using `org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager` (please note I'm using commons-httpclient 3.1, so this may not apply to other versions)

Comment: Another close duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21241233/1103872. Apparently OP has two identities here.

Comment: @AKIWEB In that sense, yes.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I opened this question here since I had similar question here on the RestTemplate which Sotirios pointed out with resttemplate so wanted to be on the same flow.. I am not duplicating any stuff here just following the proper way of not duplicating stuff, otherwise I would have posted it from that accont itself....

Comment: @Taylor Can you go into more detail about what you mean? All I see is that `RestTemplate` uses `SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory` to generate its connections and requests.

Comment: Yeah, and that's not thread safe.  I'll add an answer with my spring config for this.

Comment: @Taylor Why is it not thread safe? It uses `URL#openConnection()`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: See my update in the question, my above example is fine and it is along the line as you have stated correct?

Comment: @AKIWEB That is what I was suggesting, yes. But I still want to see what Taylor has to say about lack of thread-safety.

Comment: Perhaps this has been fixed in some more recent version, but we tried to use this multi threaded and got corrupted responses when concurrent requests were fired.

Comment: I would also avoid JDK's URLConnections for anything nontrivial. The implementation is incredibly convoluted (just go ahead and try to keep a bearing while tracing an `openConnection` call through the source). It is also not fully configurable.

Comment: @Taylor I can't find any evidence of what you are suggesting. Also `commons-httpclient-3.1` is outdated and `CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory` has been deprecated in favor of `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory`. That might be an appropriate alternative but I'm pretty sure it does similar things in the background, except it might be more configurable. Both (all 3) should be thread safe.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Don't all HTTP clients use `URLConnection` in their underlying implementation? Do some use sockets directly? I would think that worse.

Comment: Why would it be worse? Of course a competent HTTP implementation should start from a raw socket---in fact, nowadays it shouldn't touch anything related to `java.io`, anyway.

Comment: @Marko I would think it harder to work with. I'll look into some more source. Thanks.

Comment: [Here's a pointer.](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0.1/org/apache/http/impl/conn/DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java#90) BTW I truly advise you look into the implementation of URLConnection---I think you'll change your mind about "harder to work with" :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, we were stuck with the outdated commons-httpclient because at the time (not sure if this is still true) it was what spring rest template supported.  I notice now, in digging back through my version control that the httpclient in the version i used used `SimpleHttpConnectionManager` (different from what you described, apologies), which holds a `httpConnection` instance variable.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25698072/simpleclienthttprequestfactory-vs-httpcomponentsclienthttprequestfactory-for-htt) which uses `RestTemplate`. See if you can help me out? I am stuck on this for a while.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis hey, I have a similar question on RestTemplate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679918/does-resttemplate-reuse-and-pool-connections-by-default). If possible, can you help me out over there. I only see your name who answer most on RestTemplate question so thought to check with you. Any help will be greatly appreciated as I am having some basic confusion how to do it. I apologize for contacting like this.

Answer (score 5):

A `RestTemplate` [is thread safe once constructed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22989500/545127), so you can construct one instance and have all your tasks share it. That will be much more efficient,  because you eliminate the construction cost from each task, and reduce the load on the garbage collector.

Answer (score 4):

I have my multi-thread-safe singleton REST template wired like this in spring:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpConnectionManagerParams" id="httpConnectionManagerParams">
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="10000"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager" id="httpConnectionManager">
    <property name="params" ref="httpConnectionManagerParams"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.params.HttpClientParams" id="httpClientParams">
    <property name="authenticationPreemptive" value="true"/>
    <property name="soTimeout" value="10000"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient" id="httpClient">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClientParams"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="httpConnectionManager"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory" id="httpClientFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClient"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth.consumer.client.OAuthRestTemplate" id="restTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpClientFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="myResource"/>
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Please note I'm using an `OAuthRestTemplate`, and `myResource` refers to the oauth resource stuff which I've omitted as it's not relevant.  Instead of an `OAuthRestTemplate` you could just as easily use a `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html