# Android to WCF connection reset by peer

Tags: java, android, wcf, spring-rest

I have android application which uses WCF services, here is my code snippet from `AsyncTask`:

```
private HttpEntity<HashMap> request(){
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.add("Cookie", LocalData.Web.getCookie(this.context));

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());

        HttpEntity<HashMap> requestDataEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request, requestHeaders);

        HttpEntity<HashMap> response = restTemplate.exchange(this.url, this.httpMethod, requestDataEntity, HashMap.class);


//        HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
//        LocalData.Web.storeCookie(headers, context);

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected HashMap doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try{
            return request().getBody();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }
```

mainly it connects properly to this service, but sometimes here occurs some exception which gets this message:

> I/O error: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer);
>   nested exception is java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed:
>   ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

what may cause this error?

**Note:**

It was worked fine long time, but now I often have this problem. Is it a android problem or I would search problem in WCF side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting for HttpURLConnection before connecting:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("connection", "close");
```

Also you can have a look at [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). Android maintains the pool of connections and uses the old one first, so by setting this property you will disable `keep-alive` property which is on by default.

Todo this you have to create `RestTemplate`[HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html)

```
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory) {
   return new RestTemplate(factory);
}
```

[Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304006/persistent-httpurlconnection-in-java)

[and this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242812/how-to-use-resttemplate-efficiently-in-multithreaded-environment)

Comment: where do I write this? can you explain more clearly?

Comment: I don't understand where would I insert this code in my snippet :/

Comment: you have to write `RestTamplate` class. check the answer for reference links